# app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-multidex

I encounter this mistake

> app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. > java.io.IOException: Can't write [AppFinal\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] (Can't read [.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-27.1.0.aar\1e1d11e393fd1de952998ec34dc775f1\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$Behavior.class]))

this is my build.gradle (module: app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId ""
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.+'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'
implementation   "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.6.1"
}






apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my code for build.grad (project: app)

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.24.4'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
    }
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I'm getting this error when I rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

You have added `com.android.support:design` dependencies  for three time,keep it only one time also use same version for all dependencies.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.6.+'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'
implementation   "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.6.1"
}
```

Comment: I made the alterations, cleaned the project and rebuildit, but I still encounter the same mistake

Comment: I also tried to invalidate the cache and execute, also the same error occurs

Comment: have you removed multiple dependencies  `com.android.support:design`